# Simple Iphone XML Example

Tags: xml, parsing, iphone-sdk-3.0

I a bit overwhelmed with all of the sample code I've seen on the apple dev site.
I'm looking for a simple example to show me how to load an xml file from a server into iphone.
I would like to read url's from this xml file and load an image.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to create a new test project to see how does the nsxmlparser parse the xml by following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005448/how-to-use-nsxmlparser-to-parse-parent-child-elements-that-have-the-same-name)