# iphone XMLReader SOAP-Response parsing

Tags: iphone, soap, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have problems regarding the output of the XMLReader , which should be able to parse any SOAP-Result into an NSDictionary.

When I go through the results I get the following:

Key: soapEnvelope, Value: {*the rest of the xml-file to the end, with all tags, but it seems to be a long string*}

What am I doing wrong here since I expected to get a NSDictionary with all of my XML-Tags as a key?

Edit: Since I´m working and trying to understand this since days, I may be totally in the wrong direction, so if possible... here´s my XML:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetData2Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <GetData2Result>
            <NoOfObjectsDetected>1</NoOfObjectsDetected>
            <RectanglesForPicture>
                <Rectangle>
                    <Location>
                        <X>90</X>
                        <Y>14</Y>
                    </Location>
                    <Size>
                        <Width>352</Width>
                        <Height>352</Height>
                    </Size>
                    <X>90</X>
                    <Y>14</Y>
                    <Width>352</Width>
                    <Height>352</Height>
                </Rectangle>
            </RectanglesForPicture>
            <ReturnMessage>Juhu!</ReturnMessage>
        </GetData2Result>
    </GetData2Response>
</soap:Body>
```

When I want to have Lets say NoOfObjectsDetected in an int - what exactly do I have to do? (It´s stupid, I know... but I´m lost atm... thx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are u parsing with the help of NSXMLParser?? here is the method. create an mutable array to store the contents of xml. in the delegate methods do the following:

nsmutablearray noOfObjetcsArray;
nsstring elementNameStr;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)atributeDict

{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NoOfObjectsDetected"])

{

noOfObjetcsArray =[nsmutablearray alloc] initwithcapacity:0];

elementNameStr = elementName;

}

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{

if ([elementNameStr isEqualToString:@"NoOfObjectsDetected"])

{

```
 [noOfObjetcsArray addObject:string];
```

}

}

---

when parsing is complete u will get the contents in the array. since u want it as an int value, wherever u use this value jus give:

[[noOfObjetcsArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]

this will convert string to int value. thats the way u can get teh value. try it.

all the best :)

}

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.elementsValues setObject:self.currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

Here elementsValues is type of NSMutableDictionary. currentElementsValue is the value of current tag. And elementName is current tag. Free to ask questions if this is not clear

Comment: Since I´m working and trying to understand this since days, I may be totally in the wrong direction, so if possible... here´s my code:

Comment: Sorry, Edited above for the xml

Comment: First you need to read tutorial about xml parsing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005448/how-to-use-nsxmlparser-to-parse-parent-child-elements-that-have-the-same-name

Comment: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

Comment: I did. A couple of times. Still lost.