# cant retrieve xml values using NSXMLParser

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

My php response in xml is of this type

```
<users>
<username>myemail</username>
<password>mypass</password>
 </users>
```

Now this is my parseUrl class

```
  NSURL *parserUrl = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString] autorelease];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:parserUrl] autorelease];
        [parser setDelegate:self];



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {



    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"users"]) 
    {
        return;
    }



    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"username"] ) 
    {
        NSString *val = [attributeDict  objectForKey:@"username"] ;    
      return;
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, the `attributeDict` is giving 0 pairs. The function is reading `username, password and users` meaning it can get inside this loop

```
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"username"] ) 
        {
            NSString *val = [attributeDict  objectForKey:@"username"] ;    
          return;
        }
```

But how can i retrieve the value of this node?

Comment: dont return and add value in array, mate .. :)

Comment: see reply on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005448/how-to-use-nsxmlparser-to-parse-parent-child-elements-that-have-the-same-name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `return` statment

and attributeDict is alway contain attributes.

e.g.

here 'id' is attribute of user.

to getting string value, you need to write

```
//take string variable in header file 'elementname'

NSString *elementname;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

elementname = elementName;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    elementname = elementName;
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

   if([elementname isEqualToString:@"username"])
   {
       NSLog(@"username : %@",string);
   }
   else if([elementname isEqualToString:@"password"])
   {
       NSLog(@"password : %@",string);
   }
}
```

Comment: mate can you explain by editing in my code? Your pointed function has returned me values in NSLog but how can i know if its username of password string. Kindly give an example to store these values wrt their type

Comment: just one thing, when i run this. Its repeated two times. Firstly it shows username : xxxx then next time it shows username : (nothing) same with password. Is this some sort of bug or it should be like that?

Comment: try this but i am not sure. i had problem but i solved that how i just not remember.      [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
it YES/NO.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
{
currentElementName = [elementName copy];

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"])
{
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"])
{
    [resultArray addObject: currentElementValue];
}
}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
NSLog(@"Result Array= %@",resultArray);
NSLog(@"list Array= %@",list);
}
```